# extract the specific columns from fixed width file in unix

Tags: unix, hadoop, hdfs

I have wide fixed width file from source.

I need to extract the few columns based on offsets and have merged file as output like if wide string is of width 1000 then i need to extract string of the range from 1 to 100 , 200 to 400, 800 to 1000 and then create new file from this.

I have used

hdfs dfs -cat /data/a.txt | cut   -b1-100 | hadoop fs -put - /data/b.txt

however it can cut only 1 to 100 , i need extract range of columns

Answer (score 0):

like this?:

```
$ cat > foo
123456789
$ cut -b 1-2,4-5 foo
1245
```